# If $0$ is the zero-object $ \Longrightarrow F(0) $ is the zero object when $F$ additive

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Let $$ F : \text{A-Mod} \to \text{A-mod} $$ be an additive functor. Then if $0$ is the zero-object $F(0) $ is the zero object. Why this is true ?

The definition of additive functor that I know is

> $\forall \ \ M , N \in $ A-Mod $$F : \hom_{A-Mod}(M,N ) \to \hom_{A-Mod}(FM,FN ) $$ is a morphism of abelian groups.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $0_M$ and ${\rm id}_M$ denote the zero map and identity map on an $A$-module $M$. We have

$$M=0\iff 0_M={\rm id}_M.$$

Since $F$ is a functor, $F({\rm id}_M)={\rm id}_{FM}$. Since it's also additive, $F(0_M)=0_{FM}$.

Comment: Why  $F(0_M)=0_{FM}$ ?

Comment: @Wlog $F:\hom(M,M)\to\hom(FM,FM)$ is an abelian group homomorphism, so it sends additive identity to additive identity (which are $0_M$ and $0_{FM}$ respectively).

Comment: ok but why the zero map $ M \to M $ is the zero of the abelian group $\hom(M,M )$ ?

Comment: @wlog do you think for $\alpha\in\hom(M,M)$ that $\alpha+0_M$ can be anything other than $\alpha$?

Comment: To add to @anon comment, an alternative way to view this is that the additive functor acts as a group homomorphism (with respect to arbitrary abelian operator one way denote $+$) on the morphism set. Being that the zero object denote the additive identity, and group homomorphism preserves identity, we reach the desired conclusion.