# An additive functor between two categories of left $R$-modules sends zero module to zero module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

The question is to show that an additive functor $F$ between two categories Of left $R$-modules will send the $0$-module to the $0$-module.

How to prove this?

Comment: What have you tried or where did you get stuck in your proof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $0$ is the zero-object $ \Longrightarrow F(0) $ is the zero object when $F$ additive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859820/if-0-is-the-zero-object-longrightarrow-f0-is-the-zero-object-when-f-a)

Comment: I am not able to understand how to apply the property of additive functor since all them seem to be on morphisms and not on objects.Like I know F will send identity morphism to identity morphism and F(f+g)=F(f)+F(g) for all morphisms f,g between two objects X and Y.

Comment: @bhavna That's the crucial property of additive functors; they induce Abelian group homomorphisms on the Hom-sets. So we get a group homomorphism from $\text{Hom}(M,M)$ to $\text{Hom}(F(M),F(M))$.  This homomorphism preserves identities.

Comment: Thank you..i got it

Answer (score 0):

Additive functors preserves zero objects. In the category of modules, zero modules are both initial and terminal, hence are preserved by additive functors.

Comment: And why do additive functors preserve zero objects?

Comment: Because by definition they preserve biproducts, and zero objects are biproducts of an empty family of objects